# vim continued forward/backward search direction

Tags: vim, nvim

Some time ago I read about an option that fixes the behavior the 'n' and 'N' keys cause when continuing a search in vim. That is, by default 'n' performs a forward search if the search was triggered with '/' but a backward search if the search was triggered with '?'.
With this option set 'n' would continue searching towards the end of the document irrespective what search mode I am in. Similarly, 'N' would unconditionally search towards the beginning of the document.

I've tried to find the reference or really any hint as to how this option is called but I was unsuccessful. Does anybody have an idea what I am referring to? It is possible that this option is actually specific to neovim. I don't recall this detail.

Comment: No such option, but over on [vi.se], see https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2365/how-can-i-get-n-to-go-forward-even-if-i-started-searching-with-or

Answer (score 1):

This is what `/` and `?` do without an argument. If `n` and `N` could be configured to do that, it might be considered redundant. There's an extra keystroke (the `<return>`), but the functionality is complete:

- `/term<return>` - search forward for `term`
- `?term<return>` - search backward for `term`
- `/<return>` - continue searching forward
- `?<return>` - continue searching backward
- `n` - continue searching in same direction
- `N` - continue searching in opposite direction

Comment: Thanks both of you for your help. I went with

```vim
nnoremap <expr> n (v:searchforward ? 'n' : 'N')
nnoremap <expr> N (v:searchforward ? 'N' : 'n')
```